# Harry Potter fanfic where Remus steals Sirius' girl after he's thrown in Azkaban

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

From what I remember of the fic, Sirius was married to James's sister. After Halloween, Sirius is arrested and his wife (OFC) raises Harry. Remus helps her to raise Harry, and they fall in love. This makes things very complicated when Sirius escapes and they realize he is innocent.